# Azure ARM Template for runbook with Powershell file from Azure Git Repo

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

We are trying to deploy a runbook with Powershell that queries Log Analytics periodically. We have it working on the portal and now we are trying tobuild a ARM Template for doing future deployments to other environments. We have our ARM (json) template and the PS1 file in the same Azure Devops Git repo and we even tried hard coding the path of PS1 file in the template but it doesnt work. Can someone please help us here on what we are doing wrong. Following is the ARM Template:-

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "automationAccountName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "Automation-XXX-INFRA-MONITORING",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Automation Account"
        }
    },
    "automationRegion": {
        "defaultValue": "eastus2",
        "type": "string",
        "allowedValues": [
            "westeurope",
            "southeastasia",
            "eastus2",
            "southcentralus",
            "japaneast",
            "northeurope",
            "canadacentral",
            "australiasoutheast",
            "centralindia",
            "westcentralus"
        ],
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Specify the region for your automation account"
        }
    },
    "_artifactsLocation": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "https://ABCD.visualstudio.com/3Pager/_git/Infrastructure?path=%2FAzure.Infra%2FAppInsights%2FMonthOverMonthTrendAnalysisReport.ps1&version=GBmaster",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "URI to artifacts location"
        }
    },
    "_artifactsLocation1": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "https://ABCD.visualstudio.com/3Pager/_git/Infrastructure?path=%2FAzure.Infra%2FAppInsights%2FMonthOverMonthTrendAnalysisReport.ps1&version=GBmaster",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "URI to artifacts location"
        }
    }
},
"variables": {
    "asrScripts": {
        "runbooks": [
            {
                "name": "Test_Runbook",
                "url": "[parameters('_artifactsLocation')]",
                "version": "1.0.0.0",
                "type": "PowerShell",
                "description": "Runbook for month over month trend analysis report"
            }
        ]
      }
},
 "resources": [

    {
        "apiVersion": "2015-10-31",
        "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('automationAccountName'), '/', variables('asrScripts').runbooks[copyIndex()].Name)]",
        "location": "[parameters('automationRegion')]", 
        "copy": {
            "name": "runbooksLoop",
            "count": "[length(variables('asrScripts').runbooks)]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "description": "[variables('asrScripts').runbooks[copyIndex()].description]",
            "runbookType": "[variables('asrScripts').runbooks[copyIndex()].type]",
            "logProgress": false,
            "logVerbose": true,
             "publishContentLink": { 
                 "uri":"[parameters('_artifactsLocation1')]",
                 "version": "[variables('asrScripts').runbooks[copyIndex()].version]"                  } 

        }
    }
],
"outputs": {}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending a URI to ARM telling it where to find the runbooks.  When the AutomationAccount/runbooks resource type is created it will make a GET call to the publishContentLink.url in order to get the content from the URI.  If Azure can't access that URI (presumably your visualstudio.com URI is not publicly accessible) then it won't be able to access the runbook content and the deployment will fail.

The solution is to make sure the publishContentLink URI is something accessible to the Azure Automation service.  You can do this a couple ways:

1. Put the content in a publicly accessible URI such as Github or a public Blob Storage container.
2. Create a SAS token to the content.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-tutorial-secure-artifacts shows an example of how to do this with Azure Storage, or https://xebia.com/blog/setting-up-vsts-with-arm-templates/ for doing it with VSTS.

Comment: Thank you Kwill, we ended up using Storage account and saving stuff to Storage account and using it in Azure DevOps pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving it here in case someone has similar issue. For a private Azure DevOps Repo it can be solved by Azure Function with HTTP trigger and following PowerShell script:

```
using namespace System.Net

# Input bindings are passed in via param block.
param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
    
# Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
$adouri = $Request.Query.adouri
$pat = $Request.Query.pat

if (!$adouri){
    $response = "Please pass uri"
    Write-Warning "URI not passed" -Warning
} elseif (!$pat){
    $response = "Please pass pat"
    Write-Warning "PAT not passed" -Warning
} else {
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))
    $headers = @{
        "Authorization" = ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)
    }
    
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $adouri -Method Get -ContentType "application/text" -Headers $headers
}

# Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
    StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
    Body = $response
})
```

Once the function is ready, it can be called then directly from ARM template, e.g.:

```
"variables": {    
    "runbookUri": "https://[function name].azurewebsites.net/api/[trigger name]?adouri=https://dev.azure.com/[ADO Organization]/[ADO project]/_apis/git/repositories/[Repo]/items?path=%2F[folder]%2F[subfolder]%2Fscript.ps1&pat=[token]"
  },
"resources": [    
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/runbooks",
  "apiVersion": "2018-06-30",
  "name": "[name]",
  "location": "[location]"
  "properties": {
    "runbookType": "PowerShell",
    "logVerbose": false,
    "logProgress": false,
    "logActivityTrace": 0,
    "publishContentLink": {
      "uri": "[variables('runbookUri')]"
    }
  }
}]
```

Token is just the Personal Access Token from Azure DevOps. To keep it secured it can be passed to the ARM template from a secret ADO variable or Azure KeyVault.

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this limitation by using Terraform templates. They offer the possibility to publish custom content into a runbook by using local paths. So you can do this either directly from the Git repository file system (your pc), or by linking an Azure Pipeline to your repository and using the file as an artifact.

If interested, check https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/automation_runbook in the "Example Usage - custom content".